# Geocoding a DBF table on ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geocoding, dbf, address

I am trying to geocode address onto a map in ArcGIS 10.3. The table is in dbf format and contains address, city, state, and zip.

I have attempted going to ArcCatalog and adding an address locator. I choose US address (Dual Ranges) and then select my table as the reference, but I receive a red "x" that says "Not enough reference data tables for this style"

Is there another way to display these addresses on my map? Or is there another way to use my table and use the address locator.

Comment: Are you using the right address locator for your data?  [Commonly used address locator styles](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geocoding/commonly-used-address-locator-styles.htm)

Comment: Do you have an address locator already, or are you wanting to use a [Geocoding service](https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/index.html)?

Comment: I was trying to create an address locator in order to geocode my addresses. I was trying to use dual ranges but that didn't seem to work. If I just have addresses, city, state, and zipcode is there another style I could use?

Comment: An address locator is used to geocode tables of addresses. If you don't have an address locator already set up, creating one from your table of addresses won't work.  You'll need to use a geocoding service or an already created address locator.  You can make ArcMap use Esri's World Geocoding service as the default address locator and load your address table into that